# How to load fancybox images into browser cache after document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, browser-cache, document-ready

I have a list of ten anchored thumbnails and some facts, and when you click a thumbnail a full page chart pops up in a Fancybox window. There is a delay the first time you click any specific thumbnail as it loads the image into the cache.

How can I pre-load all of the images from the links into the browser cache so that they pop up instantly into a Fancybox the first time they are clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by creating a div not visible and containing all images that Fancybox require. And you create this div when doc is ready for sure.

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea and it works well! I'm using $(window).load(function(){$('<div style="display:none;"><img src="..." alt="" /></div>').appendTo("body");}); to append the div after all page elements have loaded. Now the next question is how to make this function dynamically grab all hrefs inside anchors with a class of .fancybox, and then add another <img src="grabbed_href" /> to the list of html to append?